# Keras explanation: number of nodes in input layer

Tags: neural-network, keras

I'm trying to understand the relationship between a simple *Perceptron* and a neural network one gets when using the keras *Sequence* class.

I learned that the neural network perceptron looks as such:

[image]

Each "node" in the first layer is one of the features of a sample x_1, x_2,...,x_n

Could somebody explain the jump to the neural network I find in the Keras package below?
Since the input layer has four nodes, does that mean that network consists of four of the perceptron networks?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is seem to be misunderstanding on what a perceptron is. A perceptron is a single unit that multiplies the inputs with weights, sums them up and applies an activation function:
[image: Perceptron]

Now the diagrams you have are called *multi-layer perceptrons (MLP)* and consist of a stack of perceptrons organised in layers, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron). In Keras, there is no explicit notion of a perceptron but of a layer of perceptrons implemented as a `Dense` layer because the layers are densely connected, ie every output is connected to every input between layers. The second diagram would correspond to:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=3))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

assuming you have sigmoid activation. In this case, the input layer is implicit by specifying the `input_dim=3` and the final layer would be the output layer.

Comment: are you sure the second diagram would correspond to that? First, *input_dim* could be anything, right? and also second line should be "...Dense(3..." ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, you are confusing input layers and hidden layers. The input dim for the second diagram is 3 because you have 3 input nodes. Then these connect to the first hidden layer which has 4 perceptrons hence Dense(4..)

Comment: Aha, I see! So the second diagram is a neural network (MLP?) that takes three-dimensional data, correct?

Comment: Yes indeed both diagrams are neural networks (MLPs) and every column / layer is like a vector of that many dimensions. In Keras you specify that output dimension for a given layer.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm getting it. I'm just also confused that the answer here under "*dim*"(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747343/keras-input-explanation-input-shape-units-batch-size-dim-etc) states that even though one puts input_dim = 3, the data is "one-dimensional"

Comment: That is because when you have 1 dimension, you can specify your `input_dim` as a scalar. In Keras, `input_shape=(3,)` is equal to `input_dim=3`.

Comment: I’m sorry, I dont get it, a scalar is always dim = 1 in my head. Thanks fir trying tho :)

Comment: That's it then, no a scalar is dimension 0, have a look at how [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/programmers_guide/dims_types) describes things.