# Tensorflow——keras model.save() raise NotImplementedError

Tags: python, keras

```py
import tensorflow as tf 

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist 

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer ='adam',
            loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)
```

When I tried to save the model

```py
model.save('epic_num_reader.model')
```

I get a NotImplementedError:

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-99efa4bdc06e> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 model.save('epic_num_reader.model')

NotImplementedError: Currently `save` requires model to be a graph network. Consider using `save_weights`, in order to save the weights of the model.
```

So how can I save the model defined in the code?

Comment: Ah I see you were also trying the tutorial at https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/. Glad to see you've already found a solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot the `input_shape` argument in the definition of the first layer, which makes the model undefined, and saving undefined models has not been implemented yet, which triggers the error.

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (my, input, shape)))
```

Just add the `input_shape` to the first layer and it should work fine.

Comment: This is a great answer.Thank you.

Comment: I follow the same sentdex tutorial and changed the code to `model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=x_train.shape))` buI got `expected flatten_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)` when run `model.fit()`. What should the code be exactly?

Comment: @hanaZ Input shape should not contain the batch/samples dimension, and in the future remember that comments are to clarify questions and answers, not to introduce your own.

Comment: @Matias. Thanks much for the reply. I tried with `model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=x_train[0].shape))` , then it worked.

Comment: It will work fine, but I found that the performance of my model dropped massively and [asked a question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054119/what-is-the-structure-of-a-keras-model-if-input-shape-is-omitted-and-why-does-it) (currently unexplained)

Comment: If that's the reason, why doesn't it work after calling `model.build(input_shape)`?

Comment: Specifically, you have to add the following code.
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)))

Answer (score 3):

For those who still have not solved the problem even did as Matias suggested, you can consider using `tf.keras.models.save_model()` and `load_model()`. In my case, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
tf.keras.models.save_model
```

Works here (tensorflow 1.12.0) (even when the input_shape is unspecified)

Answer (score 1):

## Reason For the Error:

I was getting the same error and tried the above answers but got errors. But I find a solution to the problem that I will share below:

Check whether you passed input_shape at the time of defining the input layer of the model if not you will get an error at the time of saving and loading the model.

## How to define input_shape?

Lets consider the one example If you use minst dataset:

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

It consists of images of handwritten digits 0-9 of size 28 x 28 resolution each.
For this, we can define input shape as (28,28) without mentioning batch size as follows:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
```

In this way, you can give input shape by looking at your input training dataset.

## Save your trained model:

Now after training and testing the model we can save our model. Following code worked for me it did not change the accuracy as well after reloading the model:

**by using save_model()**

```
import tensorflow as tf    
tf.keras.models.save_model(
    model,
    "your_trained_model.model",
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True
)
```

**by using .save()**

```
your_trained_model.save('your_trained_model.model')

del model  # deletes the existing model
```

## Now load the model which we saved :

```
model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model("your_trained_model.model")
```

For more details refer to this link: [Keras input explanation: input_shape, units, batch_size, dim, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747343/keras-input-explanation-input-shape-units-batch-size-dim-etc)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- Success, please check -->

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
plt.imshow(x_train[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

plt.imshow(x_train[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=x_train[0].shape))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(val_loss)
print(val_acc)
model.save('epic_num_reader.model')
```