# What is the structure of a Keras model if input_shape is omitted and why does it perform better?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I omitted the `input_shape` in the first layer of my Keras model by mistake. Eventually I noticed this and fixed it – and my model's performance dropped dramatically.

Looking at the structure of the model with and without `input_shape`, I discovered that the better-performing model has the output shape of `multiple`. Moreover, plotting it with `plot_model` shows no connections between the layers:

[image]

When it comes to performance, the model I understand (with input_shape) achieves a validation loss of 4.0513 (MSE) after 10 epochs with my test code (below), while the "weird" model manages 1.3218 – and the difference only increases with more epochs.

Model definition:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(1001,)))
#                                   add or remove this  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.05))
...
```

(never mind the details, this is just a model that demonstrates the difference in performance with and without input_shape)

**So what is happening in the better-performing model?** What is `multiple`? How are the layers really connected? How could I build this same model while also specifying `input_shape`?

Complete script:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
import math, random

def func(x):
    return math.sin(x)*5 + math.sin(x*1.8)*4 + math.sin(x/4)*5

def get_data():
    x = 0
    dx = 0.1
    q = deque()
    r = 0
    data = np.zeros((100000, 1002), np.float32)
    while True:
        x = x + dx
        sig = func(x)
        q.append(sig)
        if len(q) < 1000:
            continue

        arr = np.array(q, np.float32)

        for k in range(10):
            xx = random.uniform(0.1, 9.9)
            data[r, :1000] = arr[:1000]
            data[r, 1000] = 5*xx #scale for easier fitting
            data[r, 1001] = func(x + xx)
            r = r + 1
            if r >= data.shape[0]:
                break

        if r >= data.shape[0]:
            break

        q.popleft()

    inputs = data[:, :1001]
    outputs = data[:, 1001]
    return (inputs, outputs)

np.random.seed(1)
tf.set_random_seed(1)
random.seed(1)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(1001,)))
#                                   add or remove this  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.05))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.05))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.05))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.05))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(
    loss = 'mse',
    optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.0005),
    metrics = ['mae', 'mse'])

inputs, outputs = get_data()

hist = model.fit(inputs, outputs, epochs=10, validation_split=0.1)

print("Final val_loss is", hist.history['val_loss'][-1])
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my machine (in both cases the models achieve ~6.5 training loss and ~3.5 validation loss). Further, I can't reproduce the part you mentioned about model summary. They are identical for me. As for the `input_shape` argument, if you don't specify it Keras would automatically infer that based on the input data you provide to the model when calling `fit`. Are you sure the only difference you make to the model is removing `input_shape` argument?

Comment: @today Any thoughts on what could be different on my machine? Tried it again just in case, 1.75 training and validation loss if I remove input_shape. I'd write it off as a bug had it not produced a dramatic improvement (which I double-checked with pyplot to make sure it really is producing good fits)

Comment: Further, try set a random seed, at least for the data generation stage, when you want to compare the performance of two models.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug in Keras/TF. It may be just a coincidence because of random weight initialization or random data generation. You should follow the reproducible guidelines here. Anyway, try upgrading both TF and Keras and see if this is still observed (but I doubt it to be a bug in Keras/TF).

Comment: @today Good point. I have updated the question to make it 100% repeatable. 4.0513 vs 1.3218 with seed value 1. Other seed values also show a dramatic improvement.

Comment: Nope, for me the models perform almost the same, as expected. Are you sure you are comparing "mse" with "mse" and "mae" with "mae"?

Comment: @today I'm just looking at the final `val_loss` (which is mse) after changing exactly one thing. Do you get 4.0513 with the above script? I'm on TF 1.12.0 (CPU), python 3.6.8, Windows.

Comment: I ran this again and got 3.6 and 3.8 for val loss. I am using TF 1.8 (GPU) and Python 3.5, Ubuntu 16.04. So the difference is not significant. And note that you have not yet fully covered reproduciblity. For example, you have not account for parallelism. Read [this guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development) for more info in this regard.

Comment: @today Although I argued in favor of weight initialization in my answer, I'm not 100% convinced this is the only cause. In the meantime I tried running for various `tf.set_random_seed` and always the loss fluctuated about some values which where significantly smaller for the "without `input_shape`" than for "with `input_shape`" (significantly here means that fluctuations are one order of magnitude smaller than absolute difference between values). This indicates some systematic discrepancy but I can't figure out what it would be.

Comment: @RomanStarkov How did you obtain your installation of tensorflow (`pip`, `conda`, ...)? Can you provide a corresponding environment dump (`pip freeze`, `conda list`)? After performing some additional runs I can reproduce the discrepancy between models but I can't reproduce your exact numbers though I'm running on the same tensorflow version as you do (I'm using Python 3.6.7 on Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: @a_guest Here's my [`pip freeze`](https://gist.github.com/rstarkov/f4c9dea6ec47b50bf1944eb8e09615fa). Installed with pip. FWIW, I got the same numbers from `tensorflow-gpu` running in CPU mode. Maybe one of the RNGs is different on Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

The reason that the results are different is because the two models have different initial weights. The fact that one performs (significantly) better than the other is purely by chance and as @today mentioned the results they obtain are approximately similar.

## Details

As the documentation for [`tf.set_random_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_random_seed) explains, random operations use two seeds, the *graph-level seed* and the *operation specific seed*; `tf.set_random_seed` sets the graph-level seed:

> Operations that rely on a random seed actually derive it from two seeds: the graph-level and operation-level seeds. This sets the graph-level seed.

Taking a look at the definition for `Dense` we see that [the default kernel initializer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L904) is `'glorot_uniform'` (let's only consider the kernel initializer here but the same holds for the bias initializer). Walking farther through the source code we'll eventually find out that this fetches the [`GlorotUniform`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L1120) with default arguments. Specifically the [random number generator seed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L1138) for that *specific* operation (namely weight initialization) is set to `None`. Now if we check where this seed is used, we find it is passed to [`random_ops.truncated_normal`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L477) for example. This in turn (as do all random operations) fetches now the *two* seeds, one being the graph-level seed and the other the operation specific seed: [`seed1, seed2 = random_seed.get_seed(seed)`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py#L173). We can check the definition of the `get_seed` function and we find that if the operation specific seed is not given (which is our case) then it is derived from properties of the current graph: [`op_seed = ops.get_default_graph()._last_id`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/framework/random_seed.py#L70). The corresponding part of the `tf.set_random_seed` docs read:

> 2. If the graph-level seed is set, but the operation seed is not: The system deterministically picks an operation seed in conjunction with the graph-level seed so that it gets a unique random sequence.

Now coming back to original problem, it makes a difference for the graph structure if `input_shape` is defined or not. Again looking at a bit of source code we find that [`Sequential.add`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py#L123) builds the inputs and outputs of the network incrementally *only* if `input_shape` was specified; otherwise it just stores a list of layers (`model._layers`); compare `model.inputs, model.outputs` for the two definitions. The output is incrementally built by [calling the layers directly](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py#L175) which dispatches to [`Layer.__call__`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L664). This wrapper builds the layer, sets the layer's inputs and outputs and adds some metadata to the outputs; also it uses an [`ops.name_scope`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L712) to group operations. We can see this from the visualization provided by [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graph_viz) (example for the simplified model architecture of `Input -> Dense -> Dropout -> Dense`):

[image: Tensorboard visualization]

Now in the case we didn't specify `input_shape` all the model has is a list of layers. Even after having called `compile` the model is actually [not compiled](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L434) (just attributes such as the optimizer are set). Instead it is compiled "on the fly" when for the first time data is passed in to the model. This happens in in [`model._standardize_weights`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1007): the model output is obtained via [`self.call(dummy_input_values, training=training)`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1330). Checking this method we find that it [builds the layers](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py#L237) (note that the model is not yet built) and then [computes the output incrementally](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py#L250) by using `Layer.call` (not `__call__`). This leaves out all the meta data and also the grouping of operations and hence results in a different structure of the graph (though its computational operations are all the same). Again checking Tensorboard we find:

[image: Tensorboard visualization]

Expanding both graphs we would find that they contain the same operations, grouped differently together. However this has the effect that the `keras.backend.get_session().graph._last_id` is different for both definitions and hence results in a different seed for the random operations:

```
# With `input_shape`:
>>> keras.backend.get_session().graph._last_id
303
# Without `input_shape`:
>>> keras.backend.get_session().graph._last_id
7
```

## Performance results

I used the OP's code with some modifications in order to have similar random operations:

- Added the steps described [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development) to ensure reproducibility in terms of randomization,
- Set random seeds for `Dense` and `Dropout` variable initialization,
- Removed `validation_split` since the splitting happens before "on the fly" compilation of the model without `input_shape` and hence might interfere with the seed,
- Set `shuffle = False` since this might use a separate operation specific seed.

This is the complete code (in addition I performed `export PYTHONHASHSEED=0` before running the script):

```
from collections import deque
from functools import partial
import math
import random
import sys
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


seed = int(sys.argv[1])

np.random.seed(1)
tf.set_random_seed(seed)
random.seed(1)
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                              inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
keras.backend.set_session(sess)


def func(x):
    return math.sin(x)*5 + math.sin(x*1.8)*4 + math.sin(x/4)*5


def get_data():
    x = 0
    dx = 0.1
    q = deque()
    r = 0
    data = np.zeros((100000, 1002), np.float32)
    while True:
        x = x + dx
        sig = func(x)
        q.append(sig)
        if len(q) < 1000:
            continue

        arr = np.array(q, np.float32)

        for k in range(10):
            xx = random.uniform(0.1, 9.9)
            data[r, :1000] = arr[:1000]
            data[r, 1000] = 5*xx #scale for easier fitting
            data[r, 1001] = func(x + xx)
            r = r + 1
            if r >= data.shape[0]:
                break

        if r >= data.shape[0]:
            break

        q.popleft()

    inputs = data[:, :1001]
    outputs = data[:, 1001]
    return (inputs, outputs)


Dense = partial(keras.layers.Dense, kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=1))
Dropout = partial(keras.layers.Dropout, seed=1)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu,
    # input_shape=(1001,)
))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(
    loss = 'mse',
    optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.0005)
)

inputs, outputs = get_data()
shuffled = np.arange(len(inputs))
np.random.shuffle(shuffled)
inputs = inputs[shuffled]
outputs = outputs[shuffled]

hist = model.fit(inputs, outputs[:, None], epochs=10, shuffle=False)
np.save('without.{:d}.loss.npy'.format(seed), hist.history['loss'])
```

With this code I'd actually expect to obtain similar results for both approaches however it turns out that they are not equal:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
    python run.py $i
done
```

Plot the mean loss +/- 1 std. dev.:

[image: Performance per epoch]

### Initial weights and initial prediction

I verified that the initial weights and an initial prediction (before fitting) is the same for the two versions:

```
inputs, outputs = get_data()

mode = 'without'
pred = model.predict(inputs)
np.save(f'{mode}.prediction.npy', pred)

for i, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    if isinstance(layer, keras.layers.Dense):
        w, b = layer.get_weights()
        np.save(f'{mode}.{i:d}.kernel.npy', w)
        np.save(f'{mode}.{i:d}.bias.npy', b)
```

and

```
for i in 0 2 4 8
do
    for data in bias kernel
    do
        diff -q "with.$i.$data.npy" "without.$i.$data.npy"
    done
done
```

### Influence of Dropout

**[ ! ]** I checked the performance after removing all `Dropout` layers and in that case the performance is actually equal. So the crux seems to lie with the Dropout layers. Actually the performance of the models without Dropout layers is the same as for the model *with* Dropout layers but *without* specifying `input_shape`. So it seems that without `input_shape` the Dropout layers are not effective.

Basically the difference between the two versions is that one uses `__call__` and the other uses `call` to compute the outputs (as explained above). Since performance is similar to without Dropout layers a possible explanation could be that the Dropout layers don't drop when `input_shape` is not specified. This could by caused by `training=False`, i.e. the layers don't recognize they are in training mode. However I don't see a reason why this would happen. Also we can consider again the Tensorboard graphs.

Specifying `input_shape`:

[image: Dropout node]

Not specifying `input_shape`:

[image: Dropout node]

where the `switch` also depends on the learning phase (as before):

[image: Dropout node, connection to switch]

To verify the `training` kwarg let's subclass `Dropout`:

```
class Dropout(keras.layers.Dropout):
    def __init__(self, rate, noise_shape=None, seed=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(rate, noise_shape=noise_shape, seed=1, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):
        training = kwargs.get('training')
        if training is None:
            training = keras.backend.learning_phase()
        print('[__call__] training: {}'.format(training))
        return super().__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        if training is None:
            training = keras.backend.learning_phase()
        print('[call]     training: {}'.format(training))
        return super().call(inputs, training)
```

I obtain similar outputs for both version, however the calls to `__call__` are missing when `input_shape` is not specified:

```
[__call__] training: Tensor("keras_learning_phase:0", shape=(), dtype=bool)
[call]     training: Tensor("keras_learning_phase:0", shape=(), dtype=bool)
[__call__] training: Tensor("keras_learning_phase:0", shape=(), dtype=bool)
[call]     training: Tensor("keras_learning_phase:0", shape=(), dtype=bool)
[__call__] training: Tensor("keras_learning_phase:0", shape=(), dtype=bool)
[call]     training: Tensor("keras_learning_phase:0", shape=(), dtype=bool)
[__call__] training: Tensor("keras_learning_phase:0", shape=(), dtype=bool)
[call]     training: Tensor("keras_learning_phase:0", shape=(), dtype=bool)
```

So I suspect that the problem lies somewhere within `__call__` but right now I can't figure out what it is.

### System

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.6.7 and Tensorflow 1.12.0 via `conda` (no GPU support):

```
$ uname -a
Linux MyPC 4.4.0-141-generic #167-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 10:40:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python --version
Python 3.6.7 :: Anaconda, Inc.
$ conda list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow                1.12.0          mkl_py36h69b6ba0_0
tensorflow-base           1.12.0          mkl_py36h3c3e929_0
```

#### Edit

I also had `keras` and `keras-base` installed (`keras-applications` and `keras-preprocessing` are required by `tensorflow`):

```
$ conda list | grep keras
keras                     2.2.4                         0  
keras-applications        1.0.6                    py36_0  
keras-base                2.2.4                    py36_0  
keras-preprocessing       1.0.5                    py36_0
```

After removing all, `keras*` and `tensorflow*`, then reinstalling `tensorflow`, the discrepancy vanished. Even after reinstalling `keras` the results remain similar. I also checked with a different virtualenv where tensorflow is installed via `pip`; also no discrepancy here. Right now I can't reproduce this discrepancy anymore. It must've been a broken installation of tensorflow.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation, it really explains what is happening and why. I'm guessing `plot_model` can be written off as "misleading" due to lack of metadata / grouping of operations. I feel there is more to it than just different initial weights, because the performance discrepancy happens with seeds 1, 2 and 3, and after 500 epochs with a fixed learning rate, it settles on a loss of ~1.0 vs ~0.2, seemingly regardless of seed. I'd love to get the improved performance while also specifying my `input_shape`.

Comment: +1! Thanks for your efforts to write this answer. I was wondering did you also account for the parallelism, as explained [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development), in your experiments as well?

Comment: @RomanStarkov I turned off parallelism according to the guide I have linked to and achieved `val_loss` of 4.4 (without using `input_shape`) vs 4.3 (using `input_shape`). So this time it did not perform better. However, I don't know why the results are slightly different even when we set the seeds and train on CPU with one thread, but the explanation provided in this answer might be one of the reasons. But, at least in my experiments, this is not the case than one model (i.e. without using `input_shape`) consistently outperforms another model (i.e. using `input_shape`).

Comment: @RomanStarkov I can reproduce your results and some further investigations suggest a problem with the `Dropout` layers when `input_shape` is not specified. Actually it looks like without `input_shape` the Dropout layers are just inactive and hence the improved results (which makes sense since they regularize). Right now, however, I couldn't figure out what exactly the difference is, maybe you have an idea? Please see my updated answer for details.

Comment: @today Thanks for the comment. I did implement all the steps as described at the FAQ link and I also added random seeds for the initialization operations plus removed some other randomness to be really aligned. After doing so it seems that the discrepancy comes from the Dropout layers which seem not to work correctly when `input_shape` is not specified. When removing the Dropout layers, the two results are exactly the same. Please see my updated answer for details. Can you reproduce the results on your machine? I'll try with different versions of tensorflow, to see what the effect is.

Comment: @RomanStarkov After reinstalling tensorflow the discrepancy vanished and I can't reproduce the results anymore. I also tried with different virtualenvs and there is no discrepancy either. Can you try and reinstall your version of tensorflow or create a fresh virtualenv and install tensorflow there?

Comment: You are spot on on both counts. Dropout layers were having no effect. I uninstalled TF and all dependencies, reinstalled, and it's fixed now. Thank you so much! P.S. I had previously switched between TF and TF-GPU several times, it's possible that this is what broke it, and I'm guessing reinstalling the dependencies is important.