# How to save a Keras subclassed model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After successful training, I cannot save this model with the line `keras.models.save_model(factoring, "basic_test_case")`. Why is this? I added some arguments to the constructor to avoid its being ill-defined, but that does not convince the Keras api.

Per this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553593/tensorflow-keras-model-save-raise-notimplementederror), this model may be missing an input layer. I tried to add the line `factoring.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(5, 100)))` but it threw the error `AttributeError: 'SumNet' object has no attribute 'add'`.

So how could I add a well-defined input layer so I can save the model? Note that I am relying on a Keras-only API, for backend reasons.

My sense is that I am missing an input layer somehow but I don't know how to add this to the class. As you can see, the submodes `g` and `f` are the workhorses but somehow the software cannot see 'their connection'.

```
import os

os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend"

import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import callbacks



def mlp2(size_in, size_out):
    hidden = 128
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(size_in, ))
    x = keras.layers.Dense(hidden, name='layer1', activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(hidden, name='layer2', activation='relu')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(hidden, name='layer3', activation='relu')(x)
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(size_out, name='layer4', activation='relu')(x)
    m = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return m

# to make the model defined, add dimension definitions to the constructor https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/


class SumNet(keras.models.Model):

    def __init__(self, units, input_shape):
        super(SumNet, self).__init__()
        #these are for our inductive bias
        self.g = mlp2(input_shape[0], 1)
        self.f = mlp2(1, units)

    def call(self, x):
        y_i = self.g(x)[:, :, 0]
        # y_i should be two-dimensional array, first dimension is as always the batch dimension.
        y = keras.backend.sum(y_i, axis=1, keepdims=True) / float(keras.backend.int_shape(y_i)[1])
        z = self.f(y)
        # this reduces the dimension again / float(keras.backend.int_shape(y_i)[1])
        return z


N = 100000
Nt = 100
X = 6 * np.random.rand(N, Nt, 5) - 3
y_i = X[..., 0] ** 2 + 6 * np.cos(2 * X[..., 2])
y = np.sum(y_i, axis=1, keepdims=False) / y_i.shape[1]
z = y ** 2
X.shape, y.shape



###### np.random.seed(0)
#  importantly, the input shape size is always the same, regardless of how many examples I have.
factoring = SumNet(units=1, input_shape=(5, 100))
# factoring.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(5, 100)))

# check if there is an argument for a maximum learning rate, set to default 10^-3
# check difference of epochs vs total steps in pytorch "scheduler" object
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3)
factoring.compile(optimizer, loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error)


# create array along first dim of X
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747343/keras-input-explanation-input-shape-units-batch-size-dim-etc
f_dim = np.arange(len(X))
training_indeces = np.random.choice(f_dim, int(.8 * f_dim.shape[0]), replace=False)
# include_idx = set(training_indeces)  #Set is more efficient, but doesn't reorder your elements if that is desireable
mask = np.array([(i in training_indeces) for i in np.arange(len(X))])
Xtrain = X[mask]
ztrain = z[mask]

Xtest = X[~mask]
ztest = z[~mask]

earlystopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor ="val_loss",
                                        mode="min", patience = 5,
                                        restore_best_weights = True)

factoring.fit(Xtrain, ztrain, batch_size=64, epochs=10, validation_split=.15, callbacks=[earlystopping])
results = factoring.evaluate(Xtest, ztest, batch_size=64)
print("test loss:", results)


keras.models.save_model(factoring, "basic_test_case")
```

Comment: .add only works on Sequential models, not on Functional ones, and possibly you have an XY problem.

Comment: Ah thank you for clarifying, what is an XY problem?

Comment: just looked it up...

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I clarified the question further to avoid said problem. Thank you for your helpful comment. :-)