# keras, MNIST classification with RNN model, problem about the output shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use keras' functional API to build a recurrent neural network, but met some problems about the output shape, any help will be appreciated.

my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, CuDNNLSTM, Dropout
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import normalize
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import np_utils

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = normalize(x_train, axis=1), normalize(x_test, axis=1)

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

feature_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28))
x = tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(128, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.0004), return_sequences=True)(feature_input)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=feature_input, outputs=y)
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

ERROR:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 10)

Comment: The error points to the target (your labels), not to the input shape. This is because the LSTM outputs a 3D shape, while the labels are 2D. You probably want to add a flatten before your softmax layer.

Comment: Thanks your reply. Yes, it it the problem about the outputs dimension problem. I added the following: x_flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x), but it still doesn't work? Can you help give a working example. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You data (targets) has shape `(60000, 10)`.

Your model's output ('dense') has shape `(None, length, 10)`.

Where `None` is the batch size (variable), `length` is the middle dimension, which mean "time steps" for an LSTM, and 10 is the units of the `Dense` layer.

Now, you don't have any sequence with time steps to process in an LSTM, it doesn't make sense. It is interpreting "image rows" as sequential time steps and "image columns" as independent features. (If this was not your intention, you simply got lucky that it didn't give you an error for trying to put an image into an LSTM)

Anyway, you can fix this error with `return_sequences=False` (discard the `length` of the sequences). Which does not mean this model is optimal for this case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Use LSTM do classification is what I want.