# Input dimension error on sequential dense network with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**This is a long question because i try to explain the more i can my problem because it's a recurrent problem for me and i really don't understand so thank you for taking the time to read me**

I want to create a sequential dense model which takes as input list with dimension like this:

[batch_size, data_dimension]

So i defined my network like this:

```
ModelDense = Sequential()

ModelDense.add(Dense(380, input_shape=(None,185), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
ModelDense.add(Dense(380, activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
ModelDense.add(Dense(380, activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
ModelDense.add(Dense(7, activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00025)

ModelDense.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

but when i use this network with input shaped like this : (1, 185) i got the error:

> Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have 3 dimensions,  but got array with shape (185, 1)

**Don't ask me why i said that my vector shape is (1, 185) and in the error message we see (185, 1) because when i check my array shape just before giving it as input to my network the shape shown is (1, 185)**

Ok, so i checked some topics then i found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747343/keras-input-explanation-input-shape-units-batch-size-dim-etc) in which is explained that :

> Dense layers require inputs as (batch_size, input_size)
>   or (batch_size, optional,...,optional, input_size)

So that is what i did idn't it ?
But i also saw that:

> Shapes in Keras :
>
> ...
>
> So, even if you used input_shape=(50,50,3), when keras sends you messages, or when you print the model summary, it will show (None,50,50,3)
>
> ...
>
> So, when defining the input shape, you ignore the batch size:
>   input_shape=(50,50,3)

Ok ! let's try i now definied my input layer like this :

```
ModelDense.add(Dense(380, input_shape=(185,), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
```

When i do a model.summary() :

> _________________________________________________________________ Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
>   ================================================================= dense (Dense)                (None, 380)               70680
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 380)               144780
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 380)               144780
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 7)                 2667
>   ================================================================= Total params: 362,907 Trainable params: 362,907 Non-trainable params:
>   0
>
> ---

Ok i think it's that i want but when i give **THE SAME** array as input i now get the error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have
>   shape (185,) but got array with shape (1,)

I'm confused, what am i misunderstanding ?

**_________EDIT__________ :**

Prediction function:

```
def predict(dense_model, state, action_size, epsilon):

    alea = np.random.rand()

    # DEBUG
    print(state)
    print(np.array(state).shape)

    output = dense_model.predict(state)

    if (epsilon > alea):
        action = random.randint(1, action_size) - 1
        flag_alea = True

    else:
        action = np.argmax(output)
        flag_alea = False

    return output, action, flag_alea
```

The line where i use my function:

```
Qs, action, flag_alea = predict(Dense_model, [state], ACTION_SIZE, Epsilon)
```

Exact result of my 'DEBUG' printing:

> [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.12410027302060064, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
>   0.18851780241253108, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2863141820958198, 0.0, 0.07328154770628756, 0.418848167539267, 0.07328154770628756, 0.2094240837696335, 0.42857142857142855, 0.0, 0.12410027302060064, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.263306220774655, 0.14740566037735847, 0.40346984062941293, 0.675310642895732, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.07328154770628756, 0.0, 0.4396892862377253, 0.0, 0.42857142857142855, 0.0, 0.12410027302060064, 0.08759635599159075, 0.0, 0.1401927621025243, 0.6755559204272007, 0.0, 0.0, 0.11564568886156315, 0.4051863857374392, 0.0, 0.0, 0.19087612139721322, 0.0, 0.07328154770628756, 0.6282722513089005, 0.14656309541257512, 0.10471204188481675, 0.42857142857142855, 0.0, 0.12410027302060064, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0974621385076755, 0.0, 0.0, 0.675310642895732, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.09543806069860661, 0.07328154770628756, 0.10471204188481675, 0.5129708339440129, 0.5233396901920598, 0.42857142857142855, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5528187746700128, 0.6755564266434103, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10086746015735323, 0.1350621285791464, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.14891426591693724, 0.5166404112353377, 0.14656309541257512, 0.10471204188481675, 0.42857142857142855, 0.00846344605088234, 0.012550643645226955, 0.0, 0.0, 0.004527776502072811, 0.0, 0.001294999849051237, 0.019391579553484917, 0.02999694086611271, 0.0026073455810546875, 0.0, 0.0, 0.016546493396162987, 0.024497902020812035, 0.00018889713101089, 0.0, 0.005568447522819042, 0.0, 0.007975691929459572, 0.01434263214468956, 0.0, 6.733229383826256e-05, 0.0012099052546545863, 0.0, 0.0001209513284265995, 0.01868056133389473, 0.025530844926834106, 0.004079729784280062, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01332627609372139, 0.026645798236131668, 0.0, 0.0, 0.007684763520956039, 0.0, 0.010554256848990917, 0.007236589677631855, 0.0013368092477321625, 0.000697580398991704, 0.00213554291985929, 0.0, 0.0021772112231701612, 0.012761476449668407, 0.015171871520578861, 0.001512336079031229, 0.0, 0.0, 0.008273545652627945, 0.01777557097375393, 0.006600575987249613, 0.0, 0.007174563594162464, 0.0, 0.004660750739276409, 0.009024208411574364, 0.0, 0.0014235835988074541, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.008785379119217396, 0.010602384805679321, 0.0024691042490303516, 0.0, 0.0, 0.003091508522629738, 0.0120345214381814, 0.003123666625469923, 0.0, 0.005664713680744171, 0.0, 0.004825159907341003, 0.0034197410568594933, 0.0030767947901040316, 0.004110954236239195, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001896441332064569, 0.002400417113676667, 0.0012791997287422419, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0021027529146522284, 0.006922871805727482, 0.004868669901043177, 0.0, 7.310241926461458e-05, 0.0]]
>
> (1, 185)

**_________EDIT2__________ :**

Error traceback:

> File ".!Qltrain.py", line 360, in 
>       Qs, action, flag_alea = predict(Dense_model, [state], ACTION_SIZE, Epsilon)   File ".\Lib\Core.py", line 336, in predict
>       output = dense_model.predict(state)   File "C:\Users\Odeven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1096, in predict
>       x, check_steps=True, steps_name='steps', steps=steps)   File "C:\Users\Odeven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 2382, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='input')   File "C:\Users\Odeven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py",
>   line 362, in standardize_input_data
>       ' but got array with shape ' + str(data_shape)) ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (185,) but got
>   array with shape (1,)

If u check out the first 3 lines you can see that the code from where the erorr is coming is the code i added in my first edit

**_______self-containing example_______**

Content of test.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import random
import numpy as np

ModelDense = Sequential()

ModelDense.add(Dense(380, input_shape=(185,), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
ModelDense.add(Dense(380, activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
ModelDense.add(Dense(380, activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
ModelDense.add(Dense(7, activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00025)

ModelDense.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])


ModelDense.summary()



def predict(dense_model, state, action_size, epsilon):

    alea = np.random.rand()

    print(state)
    print(np.array(state).shape)

    dense_model.summary()

    output = dense_model.predict(state)

    if (epsilon > alea):
        action = random.randint(1, action_size) - 1
        flag_alea = True

    else:
        action = np.argmax(output)
        flag_alea = False

    return output, action, flag_alea



state = []
state.append([np.random.rand()] * 185)
output, ac, flag = predict(ModelDense, state, 7, 0.0)

print(output)
```

Complete output:

> _________________________________________________________________ Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
>   ================================================================= dense (Dense)                (None, 380)               70680
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 380)               144780
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 380)               144780
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 7)                 2667
>   ================================================================= Total params: 362,907 Trainable params: 362,907 Non-trainable params:
>   0
>   _________________________________________________________________ [[0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739,
>   0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739, 0.11966889292971739]] (1, 185)
>   _________________________________________________________________ Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
>   ================================================================= dense (Dense)                (None, 380)               70680
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 380)               144780
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 380)               144780
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 7)                 2667
>   ================================================================= Total params: 362,907 Trainable params: 362,907 Non-trainable params:
>   0
>   _________________________________________________________________ Traceback (most recent call last):   File ".\test.py", line 47, in
>   
>       output, ac, flag = predict(ModelDense, state, 7, 0.0)   File ".\test.py", line 31, in predict
>       output = dense_model.predict(state)   File "C:\Users\Odeven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1096, in predict
>       x, check_steps=True, steps_name='steps', steps=steps)   File "C:\Users\Odeven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 2382, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='input')   File "C:\Users\Odeven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py",
>   line 362, in standardize_input_data
>       ' but got array with shape ' + str(data_shape)) ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (185,) but got
>   array with shape (1,)

Comment: Are you sure that your training input has shape (1, 158)? Both errors point that the actual shape is (158, 1)

Comment: I add my prediction function to my post, i also add the line where i'm using it and the debug message i have when i print the dimension

Comment: Are you sure that this is the part of the code that produces the error? Maybe you have an (185,1) array somewhere else and it is error'ing there. For me its not clear how the error and the code you included are related.

Comment: I am completely sure about the code executed, i add the traceback of the error, i know it's really weird that is why i really don't uderstand this error

Comment: Then make a self-containing example that reproduces the error and we can run.

Comment: Ok i just created a file named test.py in which i only wrote the important code and i get the same error, i add the content of this file in a third edit + the error traceback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196249/discussion-between-xeyes-and-matias-valdenegro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
output = dense_model.predict(state)
```

Into this:

```
output = dense_model.predict(np.array(state))
```

Seems keras gets confused if you pass a plain list to predict and might not do what you want, this way you make sure that `state` is a numpy array of the shape you expect.

Comment: Ok thank a lot ! that worked well ! I find very suprising that keras isn't interpreting a list correctly but ok i'll now always convert my list ^^. Thank for taking the time to read such a long post

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pro of Keras but I think, as @Matias Valdenegro said and since the algorithm is going to perform matrix multiplications through the network, it is expecting you to give an array.

If you have only one state on which you want to perform prediction you can expand the dim of your data as follow :

```py
state = np.expand_dims(state, axis=0)
```

Comment: When i do what you explained on a 'non numpy array' container i got the following erorr : ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 185)... so i think the best solution just is to convert my list into array :)