# Knowing what to put into a Keras Dense layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to Keras and am doing a basic Kaggle tutorial ([The Digit Recognizer](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer)). I am struggling to understand what to actually put into a `Dense` layer. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747343/keras-input-explanation-input-shape-units-batch-size-dim-etc) post to be very helpful, but my understanding isn't quite there yet.

In my `Sequential` model, I'm starting off with a `Dense` layer. But, I see some posts saying that the first layer *must* have an `input_shape` whereas I see plenty of Kaggle submissions and other examples that don't adhere to this.

1. Is an `input_shape` actually required in the first layer? Is it required at all?
2. A `Dense` layers first argument is `units`. For the life of me, I cannot find a solid explanation on what this argument should actually be. Is there some formula to run here based on the `shape` of your data? Sometimes I see rather large numbers (something like 784) in the first `Dense` layer whereas in other cases it's small (something like 10). Or, is it a total guess?

I understand that there isn't a "this is what you do for this type of data" approach to building a predictive model, but I can't understand how to even take an educated guess at what numbers to plug in here.

Here is my current model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
x_val = x_train[:10000]
y_val = labels[:10000]
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3) # , validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

My model performs *decent* (I think) as I only have about 350 misses out of 8400 images. I've got it down to about 220 with adding more layers, changing numbers, using `Dropout`, etc...

I'd really like to get a better understanding about the best way to understand what numbers I should be plugging in. And also, do I need an `input_shape`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question:
Yes, `input_shape` must be specified in the first layer, which is ,in your case, the `Flatten` layer. It is because different #param (weights & bias) needed to be initialised after compiling the model. In you case, the #pram of your first `Dense` layer will depend on the `input_shape` you specified in `Flatten` layer.

Second question:
If the `Desnse` layer is the last layer of your model, the `unit` should clearly be #classes / #outputs you want the model to perform. However, when it comes to `hidden layers`, as far as I know, there is no such a universal rule/formula to guarantee an optimal number of `unit`. It really depends on the data you feed into the model & the complexity of the task & etc... I would say it should be chosen on trial and error basis.

Edit:
Here I found some info for your second question if you really cannot be satisfied by my answer.
[EfficientNet paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11946): but it is for Convolutional Neural Networks
["Rlue of thumb"](https://www.r-bloggers.com/selecting-the-number-of-neurons-in-the-hidden-layer-of-a-neural-network/): ...