# How to fix a value error in the model expected dense?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer, valueerror

I am trying deep learning (noob) with Keras. I was trying to creat the model after loading my dataset (training & testing). My code:

```
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(train)

train=scaler.transform(train)
test=scaler.transform(test)

# Creating Deep Model


model = Sequential()

# Add an input layer
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu', input_shape=(11,)))

# Add one hidden layer
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))

# Add an output layer
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

#add improvements 
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#Train the model

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics= 
['accuracy'])

model.fit(train,train_targets,epochs=20, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
```

However, I am recieving an erro at the last line:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (11,) but got array with shape (211,)

what does the error mean? and what could be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you set your first layer to expect input shape (11,) by setting the hyperparameter to `input_shape = (11,)` and you later gave the model a shape equal to `train`. Try using: `train.shape` and check for the shape to make sure the model can work with it. You might want check this answer [Keras input explanation: input_shape, units, batch_size, dim, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747343/keras-input-explanation-input-shape-units-batch-size-dim-etc) to make sure you understand the core concepts of a neural network hyperparameters.

Comment: train.shape = (80, 211)

Comment: I changes my input_shape. it was missing a 2. However, now I am getting this error.
**if isinstance(data[0], list):

IndexError: list index out of range**