# Determine the input shape of a Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, linear-regression

I have a question about the `feature_columns` and the `input_shape` argument in `tf.keras.layers.InputLayer` and in Tensorflow.

I'm following an example which has the following code to create the feature columns:

```
feature_columns = []
latitude = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("latitude")
feature_columns.append(latitude)
longitude = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("longitude")
feature_columns.append(longitude)
fp_feature_layer = layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)
```

And below is the code to build the model:

```
def build_model(my_learning_rate, feature_layer)
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(feature_layer)
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(1,)))
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=my_learning_rate),
            loss="mean_squared_error",
            metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
```

When calling the `build_model` function, I will pass in a learning rate and the feature layer, which will be the `fp_feature_layer`. My question is that since the `feature_columns` has two features in it, which is latitude and longitude, shouldn't the `input_shape` be `(2,)` instead of `(1,)`. Or, more generally, since the code is already specifying the `feature_layer`, do we still specify the `input_shape` in `model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense()`? Shouldn't the `input_shape` be determined by the `feature_layer`? Is it how it works? Since the output is only one value for each example, `units=1` makes sense to me. But I'm having a hard time understanding the `input_shape`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747343/keras-input-explanation-input-shape-units-batch-size-dim-etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your understanding of `feature layer will know the input shape, we don't need to specify the input shape again in the first hidden layer` is correct.

So, the code can be modified from

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(1,)))
```

to

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
```

Please refer this [Comprehensive Tensorflow Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns) to understand how to use `Feature Columns` and `Feature Layer` in `Keras Sequential Model`.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!