# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [8, 28, 28]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I keep on getting this error related to input shape. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import tensorflow as tf

(xtrain, ytrain), (xtest, ytest) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics='accuracy')

history = model.fit(xtrain, ytrain,
                    validation_data=(xtest, ytest),
                    epochs=10, batch_size=8)
```

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [8, 28, 28]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The input layers of the model you created needs a 4 dimension tensor to work with but the x_train tensor you are passing to it has only 3 dimensions

This means that you have to reshape your training set with .reshape(n_images, 286, 384, 1). Now you have added an extra dimension without changing the data and your model is ready to run.

you need to reshape your x_train tensor to a 4 dimension before training your model.
for example:

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
```

for more info on keras inputs [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747343/keras-input-explanation-input-shape-units-batch-size-dim-etc)

Answer (score 14):

You need to add a channel dimension. Keras expects this data format:

```
(n_samples, height, width, channels)
```

For instance this, if your images are greyscale, they have 1 channel, and so they need to be given to Keras in this format:

```
(60000, 28, 28, 1)
```

Unfortunately, grayscale pictures will often be given/downloaded without a channel dimension, for instance in `tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data`, which will be `(60000, 28, 28)`, which is problematic.

#### Solution:

You can use `tf.expand_dims` to add a dimension

```
xtrain = tf.expand_dims(xtrain, axis=-1)
```

Now your input shape will be:

```
(60000, 28, 28, 1)
```

There are other alternatives that do the same:

```
xtrain = xtrain[..., np.newaxis]
xtrain = xtrain[..., None]
xtrain = xtrain.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
xtrain = tf.reshape(xtrain, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
xtrain = np.expand_dims(xtrain, axis=-1)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is 60000 in (60000, 28, 28, 1)

Comment: It's the number of samples

Comment: Thanks one more thing. I have tensor of shape (170, 64, 64) but when I increase its dimension it becomes (170, 4096, 1) but what I want is: (170, 64, 64, 1) how can I do that???

Comment: `np.expand_dims(your_array, axis=-1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `tf.newaxis` to add a new axis:

```
arr = tf.random.uniform(shape=(8,8,28))
print(arr.shape)
arr = arr[:,:,:,tf.newaxis]
print(arr.shape)

# (8, 8, 28)
# (8, 8, 28, 1)
```