# Is it necessary that the input to vgg16 should be a 4D array

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Is it necessary that input to VGG16 should be a 4D Array? I tried passing normal 3-D array. It did not worked. After expanding the array using np.expand_dim() then it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CNNs in keras take as input : (batch_size, img_size1, img_size2, channels)

For more information you can check "The input shape" chapter of this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44748370/12384070