# Understanding neural networks architecture visually

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network

I am following [this book](https://github.com/Sentdex/nnfs_book/blob/main/Chapter_5/Ch5_Final.py)  and I am trying to visualize the network.
This part seems tricky to me and I am trying to get my head around it by visualizing it:

```
import numpy as np
import nnfs
from nnfs.datasets import spiral_data

nnfs.init()


class Layer_Dense:

    # Layer initialization
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_neurons):
        # Initialize weights and biases
        self.weights = 0.01 * np.random.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons)
        self.biases = np.zeros((1, n_neurons))

    # Forward pass
    def forward(self, inputs):
        # Calculate output values from inputs, weights and biases
        self.output = np.dot(inputs, self.weights) + self.biases

# ReLU activation

class Activation_Relu():
   
   # forward pass
   def forward(self, inputs):
     # calculate output values from inputs
     self.output = np.maximum(0,inputs)
```

```
create dense layer with 2 input features and 3 output values
dense1 = Layer_Dense(2, 3)

# create ReLU activation which will be used with Dense layer
activation1 = Activation_Relu()

# create second dense layer with 3 input features from the previous layer and 3 output values
dense2 = Layer_Dense(3,3)
```

```
# create dataset
X, y = spiral_data(samples = 100, classes = 3)

dense1.forward(X)
activation1.forward(dense1.output)
dense2.forward(activation1.output)
```

My input data `X` is an array of 300 rows and 2 columns, meaning each of my 300 inputs will have 2 values that describes it.

The `Layer_Dense` class is initialized with parameters `(2, 3)` meaning that there are 2 inputs and 3 neurons.

At the moment my variables look like this:

```
X.shape # (300, 2) 
x[:5]
# [[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
# [ 0.00279763,  0.00970586],
# [-0.01122664,  0.01679536],
# [ 0.02998079,  0.0044075 ],
# [-0.01222386,  0.03851056]]
```

```
dense1.weights.shape
# (2, 3)

dense1.weights 
# [[0.00862166, 0.00508044, 0.00461094],
# [0.00965116, 0.00796512, 0.00558731]])

dense1.biases
# [[0., 0., 0.]]
```

```
dense1.output.shape
(300, 3)
print(dense1.output[:5])

# [[0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00]
# [8.0659374e-05 4.3710388e-05 6.5012209e-05]
# [1.5923499e-04 6.9124777e-05 1.0470775e-04]
# [2.3033096e-04 1.9152602e-04 2.7749798e-04]
# [1.9318146e-04 3.1980115e-04 4.5189835e-04]]
```

Does this configuration make my network look like so:

Where each of 300 inputs has 2 features

[image]

Or like so:

[image]

Do I understand this correctly:

1. There are 300 inputs with 2 features each
2. Each input is connected to 3 neurons in first layer, since its connected to 3 neurons there are 3 weights
3. Why the shape of weights is (2, 3) instead of (300, 3) since there are 300 inputs with 2 features each, each feature connected to 3 neurons

I have used [this](http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/index.html) to draw networks.

Comment: This seems like a pretty big and complicated question for StackOverflow; maybe see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms) to find a more appropriate StackExchange site, assuming this question doesn't gain traction here.

Comment: I added the question there but it was closed immediately.

Comment: What is "there"? There are 5 sites linked in that post, are you saying you posted it to all 5?

Comment: Sorry, I posted to meta, then I found appropriate site to ask, thank you.

Comment: Okay, yeah it's definitely not remotely appropriate for meta, glad you found an appropriate site though.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44748370/12229158) is really thorough w.r.t. NN shapes. You might find it helpful.

Comment: TL;DR: The first layer has the dimension specified by `input_shape`, which is the shape of each sample, which in your case is (2, )