# Keras Functional API: Remove the square brackets of output shape of my Input Layer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tf.keras, functional-api

Not Sequential API, but for Keras Functional API, how do I remove the '[]' of my output shape? For example, I don't want [(None,32)] instead, i want (None,32):

```
i = Input(shape=(32,))
x = Dense(16, activation='softmax')(i)
model = Model(x, y)
model.summary()
```

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_20 (InputLayer)       [(None, 32)]              0         
                                                                 
 dense_47 (Dense)            (None, 16)                528       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 528
Trainable params: 528
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keras input explanation: input\_shape, units, batch\_size, dim, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747343/keras-input-explanation-input-shape-units-batch-size-dim-etc)

Comment: in your example, the output shape of the input layer is represented as `[(None, 32)]` because the input layer takes a batch of 32-dimensional vectors as input.

it is not possible to change the way the shape is represented in the summary so it ignores batching.

Comment: Keras Functional API has [multiple inputs and multiple output](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#models_with_multiple_inputs_and_outputs) features where multiple inputs can be handled in the form of a list of tuples inside input layer. Not sure if we can modify this in `model.summary()`. However you can access input shape as tuple using `model.input_shape` explicitly.