# What does the input_shape argument to Flatten() mean?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm following along with the Tensorflow for Beginners tutorial:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner

And we come to our first line of code:

> ### Build a machine learning model
>
> Build a tf.keras.Sequential model:
>
> ```
> model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
>   tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
>   tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
>   tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
>   tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
> ])
> ```

And i'm confused by the first line:

```
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28))
```

Specifically about the `input_shape` argument.

**Why**: Because i thought the `Flatten` operation takes the previous layer and turns it into a 1-d vector; so what is the `input_shape` argument mean?

## So we consult the documentation

The documentation on `Flatten()`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Flatten

says:

> Flattens the input. Does not affect the batch size.

And specifically i'm interested in the `input_shape` argument:

> **Args**
>
> `data_format` A string, one of `channels_last` (default) or `channels_first`. The ordering of the dimensions in the inputs. channels_last corresponds to inputs with shape (`batch, ..., channels`) while channels_first corresponds to inputs with shape (`batch, channels, ...`). When unspecified, uses `image_data_format` value found in your Keras config file at `~/.keras/keras.json` (if exists) else 'channels_last'. Defaults to 'channels_last'.

There is no argument called `input_shape`.

So what does the argument mean?

### Short Version

- If i were writing TF code from the documentation, how would I know that `Flatten` takes an `input_shape` argument?
- Why is the `input_shape` argument omitted from the documention?

In other words: there must be some basic knowledge about TensorFlow that the documentation **assumes** you have, but does not document itself.

Can someone help me understand this undocumented behavior, and why it is undocumented?

### Research Effort

In addition to consulting the documentation, we have:

- [Keras input explanation: input_shape, units, batch_size, dim, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747343/keras-input-explanation-input-shape-units-batch-size-dim-etc) (isn't my question, nor answers my question)

Comment: [DWAT](https://thehritikjain.files.wordpress.com/2020/05/1_e4_ptjctmaofsrpzczbv-g-1.jpeg?w=935&h=466&crop=1), this is simply just input specification of the model. All the keras layer (Flatten, Dense) takes this argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input_shape` is an optional argument that can be added to the first layer (`Flatten` or not) of a Keras model. Keras uses its value to create an `InputLayer` implicitly.

You model is equivalent to this:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
```

To quote the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/InputLayer):

> When using `InputLayer` with the Keras Sequential model, it can be skipped by moving the `input_shape` parameter to the first layer after the `InputLayer`.

Comment: That's excellent. It's a shortcut that lets you omit an `InputLayer`.