# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv3d" is incompatible with the layer - Keras 3DConv Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I am having some trouble in reshaping my 3D data for training in the model.fit function for my 3DConv Neural Network using Tensorflow and Keras. I have added both code and console output for your information. I would really appreciate if anyone would highlight any mistakes and help me solve the issue.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf

**# Used np.load to load the four .npy files.
# Two training data files and two validation data files. First is Original data and second is labeling data
# Normalization has already been applied.**

print("x_train Shape Before Expanding: ", x_train.shape)
print("y_train Shape Before Expanding: ", y_train.shape)  # Label Data
print("x_val Shape Before Expanding: ", x_val.shape)
print("y_val Shape Before Expanding: ", y_val.shape)      # Label Data

x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)
x_val = np.expand_dims(x_val, axis=-1)
y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=-1)
y_val = np.expand_dims(y_val, axis=-1)

print("x_train Shape After Expanding: ", x_train.shape)
print("y_train Shape After Expanding: ", y_train.shape)
print("x_val Shape After Expanding: ", x_val.shape)
print("y_val Shape After Expanding: ", y_val.shape)

batch_size = 1

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))

train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
validation_dataset = validation_dataset.batch(batch_size)

# Print shapes after batching
print("\nShapes of batches in train_dataset:")
for batch in train_dataset.take(1):
    x_batch, y_batch = batch
    print("Input Batch Shape:", x_batch.shape)
    print("Output Batch Shape:", y_batch.shape)

print("\nShapes of batches in validation_dataset:")
for batch in validation_dataset.take(1):
    x_batch, y_batch = batch
    print("Input Batch Shape:", x_batch.shape)
    print("Output Batch Shape:", y_batch.shape)


# Model
inputs = keras.Input((401, 701, 255, 1))
x = layers.Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(inputs)
x = layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

x = layers.Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

x = layers.Conv3D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

x = layers.Conv3D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling3D()(x)
x = layers.Dense(units=512, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)

outputs = layers.Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="MyModel")

print(model.summary())

initial_learning_rate = 0.0001
lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate, decay_steps=100000, decay_rate=0.96, staircase=True
)

model.compile(
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule),
    metrics=["acc"]
)

epochs = 3
model.fit(train_dataset,
          validation_data=validation_dataset,
          epochs=epochs,
          shuffle=True,
          verbose=2)
```

**Console Output:**

```
x_train Shape Before Expanding: (401, 701, 255) 
y_train Shape Before Expanding: (401, 701, 255) 
x_val Shape Before Expanding: (200, 701, 255) 
y_val Shape Before Expanding: (200, 701, 255)

x_train Shape After Expanding: (401, 701, 255, 1) 
y_train Shape After Expanding: (401, 701, 255, 1) 
x_val Shape After Expanding: (200, 701, 255, 1) 
y_val Shape After Expanding: (200, 701, 255, 1)

Shapes of batches in train_dataset: 
Input Batch Shape: (1, 701, 255, 1) 
Output Batch Shape: (1, 701, 255, 1) 

Shapes of batches in validation_dataset: 
Input Batch Shape: (1, 701, 255, 1) 
Output Batch Shape: (1, 701, 255, 1)

Model: "MyModel"

input_1 (InputLayer) [(None, 401, 701, 255, 0
1)]

conv3d (Conv3D) (None, 399, 699, 253, 6 1792
4)

max_pooling3d (MaxPooling3 (None, 199, 349, 126, 6 0
D) 4)

batch_normalization (Batch (None, 199, 349, 126, 6 256
Normalization) 4)

conv3d_1 (Conv3D) (None, 197, 347, 124, 6 110656
4)

max_pooling3d_1 (MaxPoolin (None, 98, 173, 62, 64) 0
g3D)

batch_normalization_1 (Bat (None, 98, 173, 62, 64) 256
chNormalization)

conv3d_2 (Conv3D) (None, 96, 171, 60, 128 221312
)

max_pooling3d_2 (MaxPoolin (None, 48, 85, 30, 128) 0
g3D)

batch_normalization_2 (Bat (None, 48, 85, 30, 128) 512
chNormalization)

conv3d_3 (Conv3D) (None, 46, 83, 28, 256) 884992

max_pooling3d_3 (MaxPoolin (None, 23, 41, 14, 256) 0
g3D)

batch_normalization_3 (Bat (None, 23, 41, 14, 256) 1024
chNormalization)

global_average_pooling3d ( (None, 256) 0
GlobalAveragePooling3D)

dense (Dense) (None, 512) 131584

dropout (Dropout) (None, 512) 0

dense_1 (Dense) (None, 1) 513

================================================================= Total params: 1352897 (5.16 MB) Trainable params: 1351873 (5.16 MB) Non-trainable params: 1024 (4.00 KB)

None Epoch 1/3

**ValueError: Input 0 of layer "MyModel" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 401, 701, 255, 1), found shape=(None, 701, 255, 1)**
```

Answer (score 0):

The first dimension of the train and val arrays is the number of samples in the datasets. `x_train Shape After Expanding:  (401, 701, 255, 1)` means you have 401 samples of shape (701, 255, 1), see how when you take a batch of 1 you get a shape of `Input Batch Shape: (1, 701, 255, 1)`? that first element is the "`batch_size`".

If you look at [the documentation for keras.Input()](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/input/) it says:

> **shape**: A shape tuple (tuple of integers or None objects), *not including the*
> *batch size*.

You want your input to have the shape of a sample (701, 255, 1), not of the whole dataset, so that is what you would define the input as.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44748370/23034652) for a good explanation. especially the "**Shapes in Keras**" section.

This still won't work however because the shape is not 3d and will be missing a dimension for the conv3d layers. You are missing one in order to have 3 spatial dimensions and one channel dimension. See the [keras.Conv3D documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution3d/).

i.e. you need to define input as (spatial_dim1, spatial_dim2, spatial_dim3, channels), in order for the Conv3D layer to receive (batch_size, spatial_dim1, spatial_dim2, spatial_dim3, channels).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Does this mean that the number of samples is not a spatial dimension?

Comment: No, when you have a set of 5 apples you don't have 4 space-dimensional apples, you have 5 apples of 3 space-dimensions.

Your model will take one sample and make a prediction based only on that one sample.