# Why the input size ot shape is not valid?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I know that similar questions were asked before, but the solutions didn't helped me.

I have the following model:

```
        model = Sequential()

        # CNN
        model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(40, 2000, 1), activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        # CNN
        model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        # CNN
        model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        # CNN
        model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
        model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))

        optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.002, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
```

I'm trying to fit the model:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train_hot, batch_size=10, epochs=50,
                            validation_data=(X_test, y_test_hot))
```

where

```
X_train.shape = {tuple:3} (246, 40, 2000)
```

from other post I read ([Keras input_shape for conv2d and manually loaded images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895750/keras-input-shape-for-conv2d-and-manually-loaded-images)) it seems that my input is right.

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 40, 2000]
```

What am I missing ? and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

As you saw from the link you posted you must reshape your data to be 4dim.

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(246, 40, 2000, 1)
```

or

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 40, 2000, 1)
```

4D: [batch_size, img_height, img_width, number_of_channels]

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you did not include the `4-th` axis(i.e. `axis=3 or axis -1` for that matter).

Here, you can see the following:

> expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 40,
> 2000]

The None translates to the batch size, which of course is variable and set to None.

Then, you have `40`, `2000`, which should correspond to `height` and `width` respectively.

At the same time, remember that you wrote in your code that the input shape your network expects is `input_shape=(40, 2000, 1)` not `(40,2000)`.

You need to explicitly add the "color"/"number of channels" axis, the 3-rd channel in this case, so you need to either use `reshape` or `expand_dims` to achieve that.

For demonstrative purposes, suppose that `X` is of shape `(40,2000)`, then reshape `X` to `X = X.reshape(40,2000,1)`